# Does using inSampleSize >1 for downloading bitmaps in android mean that less data is downloaded?

Tags: android, bitmap, download, inputstream

In android when Bitmap is downloaded from the Internet using BitmapFactory.Options with inSampleSize > 1, its quality is reduced and it takes less memory. Does this mean that less data is downloaded?

My goal is to create thumbnails of large images and show them in GridView. I want to download as less data as possible. Don't want to download full size images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it only means that less data is loaded in memory, usually to avoid the notorious `OutOfMemoryError`. The data is downloaded with its original size but a scaled down version is loaded in memory.

Comment: Also quality of image will be worse